# MYSQL 5.0 Windows 2003 starts but port not available after Windows update

Tags: mysql, windows

My Windows 2003 server installed updates this morning and since then MYSQL starts but doesn't listen on port 3306.  I have searched for a solution but so far nothing has helped.

I get the error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

I have my firewall switched off.  I can see the mysqld process running, I've checked the MYSQL error log and event viewer. I've used netstat and can see that MYSQL is not listening on port 3306.

From various posts about the issues I have tried:

1. Trying to connect by IP eg. 127.0.0.1
2. Backing up my my.ini file and re-configuring using the MYSQL config wizard. I have since restored the original file.
3. Backing up then removing the ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 files.  I have since restored the original files.
4. Ensuring there is a firewall rule even though my firewall is off.
5. Working through my ini file to make sure that port 3306 is enabled and enabling TCP/IP connections (I've always used localhost in the past without a problem).
6. Running mysqladmin to make sure that port 3306 is specified.
7. Rebooting several times.
8. Starting my web, MYSQL and other services in various orders in case one service or another was trying to reserve the port for itself.

I'm getting no errors in the MYSQL error log and just a warning in Event Viewer: Changed limits: max_open_files: 2048  max_connections: 1024  table_cache: 507 - which I think is fine.

Comment: Whan happens when you nmap port 3306 or telnet into 3306? Is there any application listening there? You can run "netstat -abn | grep -A 1 3306" for a start.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you quick response - MYSQL definitely wasn't bound to that port however for reasons still unknown to me the MYSQL server has now started properly and the problem appears to be solved at least until the next reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for those who took the time to comment.

Miraculously the MYSQL service has now started and is running fine at least until the next re-boot.

I have no idea why it wasn't working or what changed in the environment to make it work as I changed nothing since my original question nor did I restart the service.  I suspect another service stalling / interfering with it. If I do get to the bottom of it though I will post it here.